# In a purchase data table,how to query day by day performance using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table and I just want to figure out the revenue difference by day. Like day 1 revenue and day 2=day 1- day2 so on

```
    Date            CustomerID       Quantity     Price     Revenue    
    2020-1-1             C1             4           10       40
    2020-1-2             C2             7           20       140
    2020-1-3             C3             8           50       400
    2020-1-4             C4             5           90       450
    2020-1-5             C5             8           60       480           
    2020-1-6             C6             9           100      900
```

The expected result is

```
Date       Revenue_Difference
2020-1-1     40   
2020-1-2     100   i.e. 140-40
2020-1-3     260   i.e. 400-140
2020-1-4     50    i.e. 450-400
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may use `LAG` here:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Revenue - LAG(Revenue, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Revenue_Difference
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Date;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, you may use a correlated subquery in place of `LAG`:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Revenue - (SELECT t2.Revenue FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.Date < t1.Date
               ORDER BY t2.Date DESC LIMIT 1) AS Revenue_Difference
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: The one with correlated sub query is working ...thanks